# Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have IG in Apex

```
SELECT invoice_id,
       line_number,
       line_type_lookup_code,
       item_description,
       quantity_invoiced,
       unit_price,
       amount
  FROM my_table
 WHERE invoice_id = :P19_INVOICE_ID
```

when the query returns data, inserting a record works fine, but if the query does not return data and I try to insert it, it returns the error Ajax call returned server error `ORA-01403: no data found for`.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting an unknown & invisible enemy.

Run the page in **debug** mode; once it raises the error, review debug info. Scroll down to the error and check what's going on - you should see a query which failed. Then you'll be able to fix it (hopefully).